# Blur executing before click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have two events: 1) Blur and Click. The blur event removes everything if the user leaves the input element empty, and the click event will show a dialog box.

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-filter',glyphiconFilterClicked);
function glyphiconFilterClicked() {
    debugger; // show dialog box goes here
}

$(document).on('blur','input',filterBlurred);
function filterBlurred() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('th').html('&nbsp;');
    }
}
```

Q: How can I say "On input blur, don't empty the parent th element if the reason is because the user just clicked on class="glyphicon-filter"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'removes everything' is it a Form reset ?

Comment: All the th elements in that row are cleared by having a non-breaking space replace the html that was in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to connect the two events. You could use setTimeout (...) in the blur event handler to wait, say 100 ms. Then in the click handler set a flag to true that the callback in setTimeout will check before wiping the value of the form field.

Edit: Some working code that I *think* works as you intend...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Filter Blur Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Apples</th>
                <td><input type="text"> <button class="glyphicon-filter">Filter...</button>
                    (defaults)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Oranges</th>
                <td><input type="text" data-filter-icon-timeout="2000"> <button class="glyphicon-filter">Filter...</button>
                    (custom timeout)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bananas</th>
                <td><input type="text" data-filter-icon-selector="a"> <a href="#" class="glyphicon-filter">Filter...</a>
                    (custom filter icon selector)</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label>Peaches</label>
            <input type="text"
                data-filter-icon-container="li"
                data-filter-icon-timeout="250"
                data-filter-icon-selector="a"
                data-filter-cleared-out-selector="label"
                data-filter-cleared-out-value="n/a">
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon-filter">Filter...</a>
            (everything but the kitchen sink)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function filterBlurred(event) {
            //console.info("blur");
            var input = event.target,
                filterIconSelector = input.getAttribute("data-filter-icon-selector") || ".glyphicon-filter",
                containerSelector  = input.getAttribute("data-filter-icon-container") || "tr",
                clearedOutSelector = input.getAttribute("data-filter-cleared-out-selector") || "th",
                clearedOutValue    = input.getAttribute("data-filter-cleared-out-value") || "&nbsp;",
                timeout            = Number(input.getAttribute("data-filter-timeout")) || 250,
                $row               = $(input).closest(containerSelector),
                $icon              = $row.find(filterIconSelector),
                clearInput = function() {
                    if (!input.value) {
                        if ($icon.attr("data-filter-icon-clicked") !== "yes") {
                            $row.find(clearedOutSelector).html(clearedOutValue);
                        }

                        $icon.attr("data-filter-icon-clicked", "");
                    }
                };

            setTimeout(clearInput, isNaN(timeout) ? 250 : timeout);
        }

        function glyphiconFilterClicked(event) {
            event.target.setAttribute("data-filter-icon-clicked", "yes");
            //console.info("click", event.target);
            event.preventDefault();
            // do other stuff
        }

        $(document)
            .on("blur", "input", filterBlurred)
            .on("click", ".glyphicon-filter", glyphiconFilterClicked);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to copy and paste into an HTML file, save it, and then load it in a browser. It is working for me in Firefox.

In this case, the "flag" is an HTML5 data-* attribute on the icon element. This makes things very customizable and reusable.

Comment: Hmm. I could call the flag something like "DontTaseMeBro".

Comment: I think what I'll do is setup a $.Deferred() variable and if the filter icon is clicked, then I'll resolve it.  Otherwise I'll wait 100 ms and assume the filter icon hasn't been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the question very well, but here is what I get, If the user blurs an input other than the one having class="glyphicon-filter" don't empty the element right ?
If so just make it as follow:

```
$(document).on('blur','input.glyphicon-filter',filterBlurred);
function filterBlurred() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('th').html('&nbsp;');
    }
}
```